# Power Automate- How to get the Display Name from MS Forms into an automated flow

Tags: forms, power-automate

Thank you all in advance for taking the time to read my question and provide some guidance.
I have created a questionnaire, using Microsoft Forms, and managed to get the responses to upload into an excel sheet via Power Automate.
I selected which fields to include in my excel table as part of my dynamic output. In essence, each time a respondent submits the survey, a new row is added to my table with all the answers filled in each column. This is my challenge now, I cannot get the "Display Name" information as part of the data that I am trying to capture. I did notice that there is an option to include the survey taker/respondent's email address but I don't need that information. I just need to include each respondent's name in my table. However, I cannot see that option (Dynamic field) to add to my Power Automate flow.
I would really appreciate any recommendations or guidance with this task.

Answer (score 0):

You could use the [Get user profile (V2)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FXcDE.png) action from the 'Office 365 Users' connector to cross-reference.